# How to get real thumbnails (not onthefly scaled down large originals) in grid from media gallery depending on certain tag using views

Tags: 7, views, media

I would like to use Views to display, in a block, real thumbnails of images uploaded using tools based on the Drupal 7 Media Gallery module in a grid of images with a certain tag.

By real thumbnails, I mean either cropped small images of the original or the entire original reduced in size. This kind of thumbnail is efficient at loading. I do not want thumbnails which are simply the browser's on-the-fly scaling down of the original.

Comment: Continuing discussion here: http://groups.drupal.org/node/183909

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out: here's my solution: http://groups.drupal.org/node/183909 credit to Drupal Gardeners Moderator Staff @mstef, @Jeannie.Finks, @Sara.Roy @mongolito404 (on groups.drupal.org/media ) for providing the basis and hints.