# How to pass the node id from a View Block to an associated Views Attachment for use in filters so that both operate on same content node id?

Tags: 7, blocks, views

What would I need to do to pass the node id from a View Block to an associated Views Attachment for use in the filters in the Attachment View so that both operate on same content node id?

My specific example is for generating preview/teaser output from a media gallery with a certain tag:

1. The title of the latest gallery with that tag
2. The latest 3 thumbnails of that gallery

(I know how to build a block view to fetch thumbnails from *galleries* (i.e plural) that have a certain tag - my solution is here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/13559/1082 I am using the Acquia Media module)

BUT what I don't know how to do is to get the title latest gallery (singular) with a certain tag followed by the latest 3 thumbnails of that gallery.

I attempted to create a block view that fetched the title of the gallery with the certain tag and I also created an view attachment to fetch the thumbnails of that gallery. But I could not work out how to pass the node id of the gallery from the block view to the attachment for it to use in its filters when fetching the thumbnails.

I tried various options including enabling the attachment to inherit arguments and filters from the block view and also contextual filters but no success so far.

Further to this, I may wish to out put more than one gallery in the teaser/preview but if I set the count to more than one on the view block I get the other gallery titles listed together followed by the thumbnails. I would want each gallery in turn to display the title followed by thumbnails that belong to it.

I would prefer to do this all withing Views i.e. not have to use PHP. I would want the solution to be as forward compatible as possible, i.e. not break with future updates - if we can stay within Views then the migration to those might be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Since the attachment is linked to a specific view block, it should gain access to the information in the block.  You can inform the block of the node ID by using contextual filters.
1. In the block  add a contextual filter of the type content:nid.
2. Since blocks do not have paths you must explicitly tell the block to find the display node, so under form heading of "When the filter value is not available", choose "Provide default value" and select "Content ID from the URL".  This should provide the Node ID to the view block.

Comment: Thanks - this looks promising but it is the view attachment that needs to be informed of the same mode id from the view block. I think of it as the view block as 'parent' having the role of displaying the title of the gallery in question and passing the node id of that to the 'child' view attachment hanging off of it that does the job of generating the thumbnails. Forgive me if not explained clear enough in the question. Would your solution apply to this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Also, when we talk of "Content ID from the URL" I would like to think that this covers scenarios as well as the conventional meaning of a URL in an address bar of the browser requesting a page from the Drupal CMS. I would hope this term caters for blocks which don't have URLs in that conventional way, presumably though I would guess there is some kind of internal URL-passing within drupal that this "Content ID from the URL" would cover. This would be what I require for my case I believe.

Comment: Update: your solution seems to work! In the attachment I needed to make the Content: Nid field appear before the Content: Gallery media field so that However the node id, from the 'parent' block view, became available as replacement pattern in the rewrite results setting in the 'child' attachment view: gallery/detail/[nid]/[media_gallery_media-fid] (the rewrite results help instructions is helpful at advising this).

Comment: Strangely though, a minor glitch I hope to remove is the display of the Nid number in the attachment even though the exclude from display box is enabled. I should figure that out and update here but any help welcome.

Comment: Next thing to do as well is to 'loop' the views so that I get this view to repeat so that I show several galleries using a tag: the gallery title followed by some image thumbnails, then another gallery title followed by some image thumbnails. And then also be able to pass the gallery tag from externally, i.e. a panel so that I can re-use this view for different category tags.

Comment: re: "...there is some kind of internal URL-passing within Drupal..."  Drupal understands only a very few  content URLs such as Node/#nid. User/#uid, and Taxonomy/#uid, basically  a few content type categories and a unique number.  The extended names are such as gallery/detail/anything are all aliases created by path and path auto modules. Although views and similar modules will see both the alias and the actual node/# paths.

Comment: "Taxonomy/#uid" - do you mean instead "Taxonomy/#tid" ? i.e. *not* using user id with taxonomy - taxonomy terms have their own taxonomy ids as in "#tid".

Comment: Yep, that's my bad!

Comment: I'm not sure whether passing data between a View block and attachment via the "Content ID from URL" setting works or is necessary, after looking at it further. It is not clear to me how this mechanism works, if at all. I've (nearly) managed to achieve my aim without this, and I will try to post screenshots of the view settings. I say nearly because I am going to need to style the resultant output and need to look at how to deploy CSS to do that - see other question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17346/in-views-admin-is-there-a-section-to-insert-css-to-style-the-view-i-e-how-to

Comment: Unaccepted the answer for now. Sorry - I wouldn't want to mislead other readers at this stage until I can really be sure.

Comment: The information in the answer is correct. The "Content ID from URL" or one of the other items in the dropdown are necessary for the block to find context information from a page the block is displayed on. The block makes the information available to the attachment associated with it.  Whether this answers your needs or not, of course, is another thing.  Good luck and please comment on how you resolve this.  Your follow up comments have been great and helpful.

Comment: +1 for your last comment @JoeS and thankyou too. I will review/re-verify what I have done and update you. I would like to try to accept your answer but I need to confirm some things first. If the reality is different from what you said feel free to use then in an edited answer - you deserve the credit for your input and time that has helped me learn.

Comment: Started looking at this question again with a view to closing it and accepting an answer: Hi @JoeS again, to recap what you said: "The "Content ID from URL" or one of the other items in the dropdown are necessary for the block to find context information from a page the block is displayed on." - even if it is the front page - which is just the bare site URL - how can any such info be derived from that?

Comment: Interesting question! I'm fairly new to this myself, so I need to review the literature :) ... I know that user info is there, possibly author info,  but what content info? Hmmm!

Comment: What makes Views hard for me to grasp is that with my software background I'm used to Object-Oriented principles and design patterns. I'm not saying Drupal Views is bad design, rather that it isn't like anything else I have come across, so I can't re-use knowledge. If it were OO I would expect to see one view as an object instance, referring to another view by having it as a data member (aggregation), so that methods can be invoked on it to get its data.

Comment: The OO inheritance concept might be another way of doing it but to me not really as it only allows one-way communication when both views express context that might be useful to the other. But this is an academic discussion about OO as Drupal Views is the way it is.

Comment: I have read that there is more OOP at the core level, but have not gone looking for it. Views goes way back in Drupal and although it has been reworked through two major releases, it would be a lot of work to recast it as OO.  Also there is Drupal's hook system and it might be difficult for Core to find hooks and call them successfully in objects.  Certainly it would require new Drupal standard requirements for coding.

Comment: +1 @JoeS for those points. As said I am not concerned that Views is not traditionally OO. As you might agree OO has its place and its not a dogma to used for its own sake. It's just that it's easier to learn something new if it uses a concept that one is already familiar with. Whatever conceptual model used by Views, I don't mind, I think the problem here is that the possible flows of information within Views is not always obvious, but it doesn't need OO to make it so, rather better visualisation and grouping and tagging of the settings.

Comment: Agreed.  The way to understand Views for me was that it is simply a UI for sql queries.  Unfortunately, I have been learning sql a the same time I learn views

Comment: "Provide default value" and select "Content ID from the URL" will work as long as the content ID you are looking for is the URL, which might not always be the case. When the content ID returned by the primary view (block) bears no relationship to the URL, this approach will not work.

Comment: I just ran across this article which reminded me of our comment discussion. Check out 'Drupal programming from an object-oriented perspective' at http://drupal.org/node/547518

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$my_arg = 1;
print views_embed_view('my_test_view', 'block_1', $my_arg);
```

views_embed_view('VIEWS_MACHINE_NAME', 'DISPLAY_ID');